# How to stop a for loop that has "include tags" in certain item in Nunjucks?

Tags: html, web, blogs, nunjucks

I have this code on my blog site but I want the loop to stop in, for example, the second item/article or third

```
<div class="container mar2ritlft">
    <div class="content3col">

        {%- for article in collections.article | reverse -%}
        {% include 'article-post.njk' %}
        {%- endfor -%}

    </div>
</div>
```

Ps: the "collections.article" is blogs that have "article" tag in the metaData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to reconsider your approach on looping through multiple articles by allowing the index of your loop to have a relationship to the actual articles.  If so, you should be able to pull off the following...

```bash
    {%- for articleTitle in collections.article | reverse -%}
      {% if loop.index > 2 %}
        {{articleTitle}} {# a collection of blog titles???#} 
        {% include "articles/article-post" + loop.index + ".njk" %}
      {% endif %}
    {%- endfor -%}
```

In your articles/ directory, you would have something like...

- article-post1.njk
- article-post2.njk
- article-post3.njk
- article-post4.njk
  ...etc...